# symfony2 lost form parameter with filter

Tags: php, forms, symfony, post, request

I need do a dropdown menu with a filter, but if I add a query builder, the request ignore the value posted.

In my form type the diference is this.

```
->add('jugador', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MSKLigaBundle:Jugadores',
    'label' => 'Jugador',
    'query_builder' => function( \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use($equipoId){
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('j') 
        ->where('j.equipo_id = :equipo')
        ->setParameter('equipo', $equipoId);
    },
    'property' => 'nombreCompleto',
    'empty_value' => "el jugador...",
    'required' => true))
```

and the other wat, with out filter...

```
 ->add('jugador', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MSKLigaBundle:Jugadores',
    'label' => 'Jugador',
    'empty_value' => "Seleccionar Jugador",
    'property' => 'nombreCompleto'))
```

thanks for any help.

**Edit:** this is the controller that processes the data

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$request = $this->getRequest();

if($request->getMethod() == 'GET')
{
    $equipoId = $request->query->get('equipo');
    $equipo = $em->getRepository('MSKLigaBundle:Equipos')->find($equipoId);
    $pena = new Penas();
    if($equipo != null)
        $pena->setEquipo( $equipo );
    else
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl( 'admin_penas'));
    $penasForm = new PenasType();
    $penasForm->setEquipo($equipoId);
    $form = $this->createForm( $penasForm, $pena);
}
else if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
{
    $pena = new Penas();
    $form = $this->createForm( new PenasType(), $pena);
    $form->bind($request);
    $pena->setPartidosPendientes( $pena->getPartidosTotales() );
    if( $form->isValid() ){
        $em->persist($pena);
        $em->flush();
    }
}

return $this->render( 'MSKLigaBundle:Penas:new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView() ) );
```

Comment: Please post the controller where you build this form.

Comment: check the value of $equipoId when you post the form if is the same, probably can't match with che query

Comment: Yes... the controller is the key, equipo ID change in the post method, and then the 'querybuilder' returns another set of "equipo", thanks!